# Websocket refresh token approach

Tags: node.js, authentication, websocket, jwt, authorization

I am developing an application where clients will receive the broadcasts from the server. I am planning to use nodejs, express and web sockets. I'll be using jwt refresh token with jwt auth token for authentication and authorization. I have prepared a mock for my approach.

Post successful login, I'll be providing an auth token with expiration time as 5 days and an access token with expiration time as 120 seconds. All the resource's access is granted based on the access token.
The client will be calling the rest server's token api to refresh the access token every 90 seconds and will update it in local storage.

Server : https://codesandbox.io/s/websocket-server-sygp1

Client : https://codesandbox.io/s/websocket-client-8b356

Is this the correct approach for authorization with websockets?

I have searched a lot for refresh token authorisation using WebSocket but haven't found anything concrete, so came up with this approach.

Comment: What is the point of two tokens? That's the question.

Comment: I have followed this https://solidgeargroup.com/refresh-token-with-jwt-authentication-node-js/ for rest apis

Comment: I see, so it is in order to reduce impersonation window. Interesting. Well, you can take advantage of the fact that WebSockets is stateful. After a user authenticates you just mark the connection on the server side that it belongs to that user. That's safe together with TLS. The only thing that it doesn't handle is reconnections obviously. For that you can use JWT with the refresh token only. You don't really need an access token.

Comment: I have added access token in case client gets hold of the auth token and shares it  with some one else. So if the token keeps on changing frequently it would be difficult for the client to do so. Wanted it to be robust so that it can't be broken.

Comment: As long as your websocket is marked as authenticated on the server side then access tokens can leak. It won't allow another user to reuse them anyway. So it's an unnecessary complication, right? This is more efficient although harder to scale well.

Comment: The access token is shared by rest api. We can easily go to the dev tools and see the rest calls. By looking at the headers we can pick up the auth code and reuse it programatically. I am using same token for socket and rest.

Comment: I am having browser client, a react app to be precise.

Comment: may I know why this question has been down voted ?

Comment: Don't know. Anyway, if you want to share authentication mechanism with the rest api, then there isn't much you can do, right? You just have to implement it over websockets. Do not worry about scalability prematurely. Reach 1000 concurrent users first, that would be really something. Also reconnections is not a problem: you have to send the api token with each message anyway.

Comment: That is what I want to know. There isn't much help for authorization using refresh tokens with websockets. I came up with this approach and wanted to know its pros and cons.

Comment: In that case my advice is: do not share authentication with REST. The problem is that JWT-like authentication was designed to work over stateless protocols. And WebSockets is not. By using JWT you need to pass a token with each message and that pretty much makes the protocol stateless. To make it stateful again you would need to manually track on the server side which token is attached to which WebSocket. This is a mess.

Comment: So how would I secure websocket ? If someone knows my socket's url he can easily create a node app to connect to it and listen all the data? I am sorry if i am being stupid, but I am a newbie to websocket, so pardon me

Comment: The basic way is this: client sends credentials, the server authenticates him and... that's it. The server marks the websocket as authenticated and so whenever something comes from client he already knows that the client is authenticated. Because stateful, brah. The only problem is reconnections. For that, you introduce tokens (you can use JWT). After authentication the server additionally sends a token to client. But the client uses the token **only** for automatic reconnection. So you have two APIs: one for "credential sign in" and second for "token sign in". Everything over TLS obviously.

Comment: Every other API does not require any token, or hashing or anything. The server just checks on his side whether the WebSocket is authenticated, which pretty much means: "is that socket in some `authenticated_sockets = {}` collection?".